# Logical Programming in java based on conditions

Tags: java, logic

i have a basic question on java and i want to implement in java.
**Questio**

i have an array of integer 1 to 50.
int a[] = {1,2,3,............50}

if a[i] is divided by 2 then it will show **"Hello"**.

if a[i] is divided by 3 then it will show **"World"**.

if a[i] is divided by 5 and 2 then it will show "**Hello World**".

i have tried the program below, but it is showing in correct output

```
    package test;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int []a = {1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if(a[i]%2==0) {
                System.out.println("Hello");
            } else if(a[i]%3==0) {
                System.out.println("World");
            } else if(a[i]%2==0 && a[i]%5==0) {
                System.out.println("Hello World");
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you mean "if a[i] is **divisible** by..." ?

Comment: _"if a[i] is divided by 5 and 2 then it will show..."_ Your final else-if clause is comparing 3 and 5, not 2 and 5.

Comment: _if a[i] is divided by 5 and 2 then it will show "Hello World"._ Your code states: `a[i]%3==0 && a[i]%5==0`.

Comment: Your last condition `else if(a[i]%3==0 && a[i]%5==0)` will never be met because it is in an `else` from `if(a[i]%3==0)`

Comment: You need to order your conditions from most specific one to more generic ones. Being divided by 2 and 5 is more specific than being divided by only 2 so you need to handle that case earlier.

Comment: @Pshemo The one in the middle is not more specific then the first one however (numbers divisible by both 2 and 3), so I would recommend to just change the "else if" to "if" if that is what the questioner wants.

Comment: How does this question have anything to do with logical programming?

Comment: @Pshemo How is it independent? For example, on a[i]=6, either the first or the second would be executed, depending on the order.

Comment: This is [FizzBuzz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizz_buzz).

Comment: @KonradHöffner You are right, I misread your previous comment (and hadn't have my coffee yet). Removed my response to it since it was simply incorrect/noise. Anyway my first comment is about case like ordering `handle blue car` or `handle car`. If we handle car first then it will also include handling blue car in a way all cars are handled, which in `if-elseif-..-elseif-else` structure makes handling blue car specially impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote "a[i] is divided by 5 and 2" but your code contains a "3":

```
} else if(a[i]%3==0 && a[i]%5==0) {
```

needs to become

```
} else if(a[i]%2==0 && a[i]%5==0) {
```

But the problem is that your if statements are ordered in a way that this 3rd option is never reached, you need to change your "else ifs" to "if" (except if you have some other intention, then you may need to reorder the statements instead, but then you have to think about what you want to do with numbers divisible by both 2 and 3 or all of 2,3 and 5).

Comment: Regarding the last statement: the solution is to either change `else if` to `if` or to delete the third condition and put `if(a[i] % 5 == 0)` inside the `if(a[i] % 2 == 0)` block, which is also clearer to read IMO.

Comment: you mean need to put conditions in correct place. like if(a[i]%2==0 && a[i]%5==0) {
                System.out.println("Hello World");
            } need to put it 1st

Comment: @Test Nope, I mean like this: `if(a[i] % 2 == 0) { if(a[i] % 5 == 0) { print("Hello world"); } else { print("Hello") } }`

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any case that could be wrong than this code below. The `IF` is improved but you can't go away from this too much.

```
    int[] values = {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20};

    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        int value = values[i];

        if (value % 2 == 0) {
            if (value % 5 == 0) {
                System.out.println("Hello World");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Hello");
            }
        } else if (value % 3 == 0) {
            System.out.println("World");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer. need to place condition in the right place

```
if(a[i]%2==0 && a[i]%5==0) {
    System.out.println("Hello World");
} else if(a[i]%3==0) {
    System.out.println("World");
} else if(a[i]%2==0) {
    System.out.println("Hello");
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Another example would be use recursion to solve it but you still reaching the `IFs`.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] values = {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20};

        check(0, values);
    }

    private static void check(int index, int[] values) {
        if (index >= values.length)
            return;

        int value = values[index];

        if (value % 2 == 0) {
            if (value % 5 == 0) {
                System.out.println("Hello World");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Hello");
            }
        } else if (value % 3 == 0) {
            System.out.println("World");
        }

        check(++index, values);
    }
}
```